# Solving the Cocktail Party Problem when the channel response of each input is known

Tags: finite-impulse-response, cocktail-party

I have a measurable $y[n]$ that is the sum of two input channels $x_1[n]$ and $x_2[n]$ according to

$$ y[n] = x_1[n] + h_0 x_2[n] + h_1 x_2[n-1] $$

where the scalar weights $h_0$ and $h_1$ are known. In this example, $x_1$ is unfiltered, and the channel effect on $x_2$ is to pass $x_2$ with an echo one sample later with relative wait $h_1/h_0$. See the following diagram.

[image]

Now, I know that if I only have one channel (let's make $x_1$ zero), I can extract $x_2$ by taking the fourier transforms $Y = \mathrm{FFT}(y)$ and $H = \mathrm{FFT}(h)$, and then get $x_2 = \mathrm{IFFT}(Y/H)$. However, I do not know how to do this when I have two channels with known responses.

I know that in general, Cocktail-party-problem solutions assume no knowledge of the channel responses $h$. But in this case, I know $h$. Is there an optimal approach to solving this problem? Perhaps some sort of Kalman filtering or maximum likelyhood algorithm?

Comment: Please check your math, I figure you mean $(h_0 * x_2)[n]$ and same for $h_1$, but then $x_2$ wouldn't recover as you wrote due to $x_2[n - 1]$, but it's indeed completely recoverable if $x_1$ is zero.

Comment: Generally, $(x_1 * h_1)[n] + (x_2 * h_2)[n]$ isn't any easier than $x_1[n] + x_2[n]$, it's like a change of variables. This changes depending on what $h_1$ and $h_2$ are; I'm unsure there's something useful to say if $h_1, h_2$ aren't specified, without losing generality w.r.t. $x_1, x_2$. The $h$'s can also make complete recovery of $x$'s impossible, if any parts of their spectra are zero.

Comment: $h_0$ is a floating point scalar. $h_1$ is a floating point scalar.  $h[n]$ = [$h_0$, $h_1$, 0, 0, 0, ...]

Comment: Your notation is unclear, I don't know what you're trying to solve. $h[n]$ doesn't make sense as you wrote it in comments, relative to $y[n]$ in the question. Are $h_0$ and $h_1$ the "channels"? Or anything that modifies $x_1$ and $x_2$? Is that the exact problem you're solving, or are there more $h_2 x_2 ...$? Do the "channels" only scale and delay the inputs? It needs to be precise.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon See the signal flow diagram that I added to this question.

Comment: You should look into ICA (independent component analysis)

Comment: if you have just 1 channel x2 there's no nned to FFT and IFFT: You already have THE channel of interest x2, problem solved.

Comment: something tells me that despite OLGD correctly pointing out that h(t) impulse response should be convolved, not multiplied to signals, in this question h0 h1 refer to weights belonging to a tap filter therefore the multiplication is the operation to perform. What is unfortunate then is that h is also chosen by the question originator to refer to channel response, causing ambiguity.

Comment: your model is a neural network, you have to train your neural network so it can tell x1 from x2.

Comment: @JonathanWheeler, Do you have the signals? If the channels are known you basically solve inverse problem. If the system is linear it becomes solving a linear system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into blind source separation here.

There is no general solution to this type of problem. You need to leverage some side knowledge about HOW the signals are different. If they have the same features in time, frequency, envelope, etc. you can't separate them.

Knowledge of the channel responses is only moderately useful. For example lest assume both inputs are have a white spectrum but have a different time envelopes. If spectrum at the output is white, chances are source one is dominant. If the output spectrum looks like the channel 2 response, chances are source 2 is dominant and you can design a Wiener Filter to steer them apart.

That's the way the real cocktails party effect works in human. By far the strongest cue is spatial, it's MUCH easier to separate two voices if they come from different directions. The human brain creates a non-linear beamformer leveraging the difference in two ear signals. Other cues are timbre of the voice, visual cues, contextual cues, etc.